# Passing template variables from URL to FormPreview in Django

Tags: django, forms, url, variables, django-templates

I'm a Django noob and fear the answer to my question is fairly obvious, but hoping someone can help.

I'm building an app that includes the same form on every page, with the content surrounding the form and the model instance to which the form data is tied dependent on a value passed in the URL. Works fine using the standard Form class and (URL, 'template.html', myapp.view) in URLconf, like so:

```
url(r'^listings/(?P<listing_id>\d+)/submit$', 'myapp.views.lister'),
```

With FormPreview, however, instead of calling the view in the URLconf, you're calling the subclass with the view functionality baked in.

```
url(r'^listings/(?P<listing_id>\d+)/submit$', PickFormPreview(PickForm)),
```

From what I can gather from the docs, FormPreview uses parse_params to pass values captured in the URL to state.self, which I believe is a dictionary. Unfortunately given my level of experience, I can't figure out from this barebones understanding how to customize my FormPreview subclass how to pass the listing_id captured in the URL to a template variable in my form.html template called by FormPreview. Do I somehow need to override parse_params? Or somehow pass state.listing_id? Or am I missing it entirely?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  The `parse_params` method in `FormPreview` does not do anything, but it is the correct method to override in your subclass.

The following example saves `listing_id` to `self.state.listing_id`, which is available in the template context.

```
class PickFormPreview(FormPreview):
    def parse_params(self, *args, **kwargs)
        """
        Saves listing_id from the url to state
        """
        self.state['listing_id'] = kwargs['listing_id']
```

Then in your template, you access it as:

Listing {{ state.listing_id }}

Comment: Fantastic! Does the trick. I knew it was something short and sweet but couldn't quite get there. I'm one of those folks who's learning Python by learning Django and see I still need to get a better handle on my *args and **kwargs. Also, you are correct re my url pattern. Seems I'm still getting the hang of the Stackoverflow interface, as well!

Comment: If you prefix the url patterns with 4 spaces, they are displayed correctly as code blocks.